# Angular Reactive Form - Control disable()

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, disabled-control

I can't find a solution to my specific Problem i have my Reactive Form where i want to disable select field based on radio element change and disable() function is not working.

Here is my form:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  } 

  createForm(): void {
    this.bsiNotesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      searchType: new FormControl(this.searchCriteriaEnum.AllNotes),
      newNotes: new FormControl(false),
      bsiNumberToSearch: new FormControl(''),
      modelsToSearch: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
    });
  }
```

Here is the toggle Function where im trying to disable the Select Field when the searchType is equals to searchCriteriaEnum.AllNotes

```js
  toggleSearchType() {
    const searchType = this.bsiNotesForm.get('searchType')?.value;
    if (searchType === this.searchCriteriaEnum.ByModel) {
      console.log(searchType)
      this.bsiNotesForm.get('modelsToSearch')?.enable();
    } else {
      this.bsiNotesForm.get('modelsToSearch')?.disable();
      console.log(searchType)
      this.bsiNotesForm.get('modelsToSearch')?.reset();
    }
  }
```

here is the select and radio  template

```js
 <custom-select
  [name]="'modelsToSearch'"
  formControlName="modelsToSearch"
  [options]="modelsData"
 >
 </custom-select>

 <custom-radio
  [options]="[
  { value: searchCriteriaEnum.AllNotes, label: 'All Notes' },
  { value: searchCriteriaEnum.ByModel, label: 'By Model' }]"
  formControlName="searchType"
  (change)="toggleSearchType()"
  >
 </custom-radio>
```

if i need to provide more code and explanation feel free to ask !

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example (stackblitz)? Would make it a lot easier to help. Don't see anything wrong with the code at first sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not answering the comments i was working on other parts of my application.
I found solution to my Problem with help of this topic
[Angular 2 - Custom Form Control - Disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163367/angular-2-custom-form-control-disable)

The problem was that i didnt used the setDisbledState() function in my custom select component. It is important when we are working with Control Value Accessor.

TS file:

```js
    disabled = false;

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
```

HTML file:

```html
     <select [disabled]="disabled" >
        <option> ... </option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you need to disable and enable the modelsToSearch field of your form depending on the change in the custom-radio selection. This seems okay, but since you have both custom-radio and custom-select fields, I am worried about a potential issue in their implementation. Another thing to consider is subscribing to the searchType valueChanges.

Comment: should i provide a code of my custom fields  ?

Comment: Of course, if you could publish your code on StackBlitz, we could assist you in a better way.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want and what exactly your problem is.